# Android Studio error. java.exe returned with a non zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently replaced a whole android project with another by over writing the project folder.  Everything was working fine and I could successfully build and run the app on my device, but ever since I've done so,  I get this error while building the project. Also I've noticed that after replacing the folder, the dependencies block of the build.gradle file is throwing an error at one of the dependencies which was not happening before.

Comment: Post your build.gradle and the stacktrace using gradlew assemble --info

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with one of the dependencies that had to be updated as my build target was version 22 and one of the dependency library had version 21. The dependency library by the way was Android Support CardView.  I updated the library and everything is working fine now.